# ASP.NET MVC C# linq query Joining 2 IEnumerable<data> resultsets together

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, join

I have a query that returns 40 records:

```
IEnumerable<SimData> simData = (from pov in db.PredictedObservedValues
                            join pod in db.PredictedObservedDetails on pov.PredictedObservedDetailsID equals pod.ID
                            join s in db.Simulations on pov.SimulationsID equals s.ID
                            where pov.PredictedObservedDetailsID == predictedObservedId && pov.ValueName == valueName
                            select new SimulationPredictedObserved()
                            {
                                TableName = pod.TableName,
                                SimulationName = s.Name,
                                ValueName = pov.ValueName,
                                PredictedValue = Math.Round((double)pov.PredictedValue, 3),
                                ObservedValue = Math.Round((double)pov.ObservedValue, 3),
                                Difference = (double?)Math.Round((double)pov.PredictedValue - (double)pov.ObservedValue, 3)
                            })
                            .Distinct();
```

I need to run this twice, each time passing a different predictedObservedID value.  The valueName is the same for both sets.

I then joined the two sets using the following:

```
IEnumerable<CombinedSimData> combinedData = (from PO1 in simData
                                         join PO2 in simData2
                                         on new {PO1.TableName, PO1.SimulationName, PO1.ValueName}
                                         equals new {PO2.TableName, PO2.SimulationName, PO2.ValueName}
                                         select new CurrentAndAcceptedDetail
                                         {
                                             TableName = PO1.TableName,
                                             SimulationName = PO1.SimulationName,
                                             ValueName = PO1.ValueName,
                                             CurrentPredictedValue = (double?)Math.Round((double)PO1.PredictedValue, 3),
                                             CurrentObservedValue = ((PO1.ObservedValue.HasValue) ? (double?)Math.Round((double)PO1.ObservedValue, 3) : 0), 
                                             CurrentDifference = ((PO1.PredictedValue.HasValue && PO1.ObservedValue.HasValue) ? (double?)Math.Round((double)PO1.PredictedValue - (double)PO1.ObservedValue, 3) : 0), 
                                             AcceptedPredictedValue = (double?)Math.Round((double)PO2.PredictedValue, 3),
                                             AcceptedObservedValue = ((PO2.ObservedValue.HasValue) ? (double?)Math.Round((double)PO2.ObservedValue, 3) : 0), 
                                             AcceptedDifference = ((PO2.PredictedValue.HasValue && PO2.ObservedValue.HasValue) ? (double?)Math.Round((double)PO2.PredictedValue - (double)PO2.ObservedValue, 3) : 0)
                                         })
                                         .Distinct();
```

Each individual query returns 40 records, however when I join the two sets together, I get 912 records.  The concatenated key used for the join is unique for each item in each query and exists in both sets of data.  I was expecting ONLY 40 records.

Can anyone explain why this is not working (ie returning 40 records), and how I can fix it?

Comment: A shot in the dark here (because your query looks fine as far as I can tell), Try add a ".ToList()" to the simdata and simdata2 query so that the enumerable materializes before running the combined query. It might also help to profile the actual sql query run on the server. 
if all else fails, it

Comment: Thanks for the help Henry, however adding .ToList() did not help.  I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a deeper look into this, I wrote a basic c# test project and mocked up the db context with some basic data.

The first thing that I noticed was the calls to Distinct. Because the query result is CurrentAndAcceptedDetail, you are not guaranteed a good "distinct" if it was run after the objects have materialized. The distinct will check against the reference to the object and not necessarily the properties of it. 
here's an [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/03/25/how-to-use-linq-methods-to-compare-objects-of-custom-types/) about it. The point is that whatever you are doing a distinct on, will need to implement IEquatable so that it can compare against another to determine if it's distinct.

Next point is the data it actually fetches. 
because the join works both ways, if there are 2 rows of "a","b","c" in simData and 2 rows of "a,"b","c" in simData2, it will actually create 4 rows, because simData.row1 is matched to both simData2.row1 and simData2.Row2. the same goes for simData.row2 and simData2.row1 and simData2.row2.

Combined together, your distinct on simData is on all the fields returned and not just the 3 fields you are joining on. so assuming we have the following data:

SimData

```
|"a"|"b"|"c"|1|2|3|
|"a"|"b"|"c"|4|5|6|
```

and

SimData2

```
|"a"|"b"|"c"|5|6|7|
|"a"|"b"|"c"|2|3|4|
```

That will spawn 4 results.

```
|"a"|"b"|"c"|1|2|3|"a"|"b"|"c"|5|6|7|
|"a"|"b"|"c"|1|2|3|"a"|"b"|"c"|2|3|4|
|"a"|"b"|"c"|4|5|6|"a"|"b"|"c"|5|6|7|
|"a"|"b"|"c"|4|5|6|"a"|"b"|"c"|2|3|4|
```

It's a little difficult to help further without actual data of what you are trying to achieve, possibly you require some group by statements to get the maximum, or find the latest records in simData. We will need a little more context to what your are trying to achieve in order to answer that.

In the meantime, Here's the code I have to test your linq queries. (Pre-Requisites: Nuget Packages for Moq and EntityFramework on a Unit Test Project)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

namespace StackOverflow.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Question44126393
    {
        public class PredictedObservedValue
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int PredictedObservedDetailsID { get; set; }
            public int SimulationsID { get; set; }
            public string ValueName { get; set; }
            public decimal PredictedValue { get; set; }
            public decimal ObservedValue { get; set; }
        }

        public class PredictedObservedDetail
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string TableName { get; set; }
        }
        public class Simulation
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class SimulationPredictedObserved
        {
            public string TableName { get; set; }
            public string SimulationName { get; set; }
            public string ValueName { get; set; }
            public double? PredictedValue { get; set; }
            public double? ObservedValue { get; set; }
            public double? Difference { get; set; }
        }

        public class CurrentAndAcceptedDetail : IEquatable<CurrentAndAcceptedDetail>
        {
            public string TableName { get; set; }
            public string SimulationName { get; set; }
            public string ValueName { get; set; }
            public double? CurrentPredictedValue { get; set; }
            public double? CurrentObservedValue { get; set; }
            public double? CurrentDifference { get; set; }
            public double? AcceptedPredictedValue { get; set; }
            public double? AcceptedObservedValue { get; set; }
            public double? AcceptedDifference { get; set; }

            public bool Equals(CurrentAndAcceptedDetail other)
            {
                return other != null &&
                    TableName == other.TableName &&
                    SimulationName == other.SimulationName &&
                    ValueName == other.ValueName &&
                    Nullable.Equals(CurrentPredictedValue, other.CurrentPredictedValue) &&
                    Nullable.Equals(CurrentObservedValue, other.CurrentObservedValue) &&
                    Nullable.Equals(CurrentDifference, other.CurrentDifference) &&
                    Nullable.Equals(AcceptedPredictedValue, other.AcceptedPredictedValue) &&
                    Nullable.Equals(AcceptedObservedValue, other.AcceptedObservedValue) &&
                    Nullable.Equals(AcceptedDifference, other.AcceptedDifference);
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                var texts = TableName + SimulationName + ValueName;

                // Calculate the hash code for the object.
                return texts.GetHashCode();

            }
        }

        public class BaseDatacontext : DbContext
        {
            public virtual DbSet<PredictedObservedValue> PredictedObservedValues { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<PredictedObservedDetail> PredictedObservedDetails { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Simulation> Simulations { get; set; }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethodLinq()
        {
            var fakePredictedObservedValues = new List<PredictedObservedValue>
            {
                new PredictedObservedValue
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    SimulationsID = 2,
                    PredictedObservedDetailsID = 3,
                    ValueName = "Value A",
                    PredictedValue = 5,
                    ObservedValue = 1
                },
                new PredictedObservedValue
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    SimulationsID = 2,
                    PredictedObservedDetailsID = 6,
                    ValueName = "Value A",
                    PredictedValue = 3,
                    ObservedValue = 20
                },
                new PredictedObservedValue
                {
                    ID = 3,
                    SimulationsID = 2,
                    PredictedObservedDetailsID = 3,
                    ValueName = "Value A",
                    PredictedValue = 5,
                    ObservedValue = 2
                },
                new PredictedObservedValue
                {
                    ID = 4,
                    SimulationsID = 2,
                    PredictedObservedDetailsID = 6,
                    ValueName = "Value A",
                    PredictedValue = 3,
                    ObservedValue = 19
                },
            };

            var fakePredictedObservedDetails = new List<PredictedObservedDetail>
            {
                new PredictedObservedDetail
                {
                    ID = 3,
                    TableName = "Table Z",
                },
                new PredictedObservedDetail
                {
                    ID = 6,
                    TableName = "Table Z",
                },
            };

            var fakeSimulations = new List<Simulation>
            {
                new Simulation
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    Name = "Simulation 2",
                },
                new Simulation
                {
                    ID = 7,
                    Name = "Simulation 7",
                },
            };

            var fakePredictedObservedValueSet = GetMockDbSet(fakePredictedObservedValues.AsQueryable());
            var fakePredictedObservedDetailSet = GetMockDbSet(fakePredictedObservedDetails.AsQueryable());
            var fakeSimluationsSet = GetMockDbSet(fakeSimulations.AsQueryable());

            var fakeDbContext = new Mock<BaseDatacontext>();
            fakeDbContext.Setup(db => db.PredictedObservedValues).Returns(fakePredictedObservedValueSet.Object);
            fakeDbContext.Setup(db => db.PredictedObservedDetails).Returns(fakePredictedObservedDetailSet.Object);
            fakeDbContext.Setup(db => db.Simulations).Returns(fakeSimluationsSet.Object);

            var simData = GetValueSummary(fakeDbContext.Object, 3, "Value A");
            var simData2 = GetValueSummary(fakeDbContext.Object, 6, "Value A");
            var combinedData = (from PO1 in simData
                                join PO2 in simData2
                                on new { PO1.TableName, PO1.SimulationName, PO1.ValueName }
                                equals new { PO2.TableName, PO2.SimulationName, PO2.ValueName }
                                select new CurrentAndAcceptedDetail
                                {
                                    TableName = PO1.TableName,
                                    SimulationName = PO1.SimulationName,
                                    ValueName = PO1.ValueName,
                                    CurrentPredictedValue = (double?)Math.Round((double)PO1.PredictedValue, 3),
                                    CurrentObservedValue = ((PO1.ObservedValue.HasValue) ? (double?)Math.Round((double)PO1.ObservedValue, 3) : 0),
                                    CurrentDifference = ((PO1.PredictedValue.HasValue && PO1.ObservedValue.HasValue) ? (double?)Math.Round((double)PO1.PredictedValue - (double)PO1.ObservedValue, 3) : 0),
                                    AcceptedPredictedValue = (double?)Math.Round((double)PO2.PredictedValue, 3),
                                    AcceptedObservedValue = ((PO2.ObservedValue.HasValue) ? (double?)Math.Round((double)PO2.ObservedValue, 3) : 0),
                                    AcceptedDifference = ((PO2.PredictedValue.HasValue && PO2.ObservedValue.HasValue) ? (double?)Math.Round((double)PO2.PredictedValue - (double)PO2.ObservedValue, 3) : 0)
                                })
                                .Distinct();

            Assert.AreEqual(2, combinedData.Count());
        }

        public Mock<DbSet<T>> GetMockDbSet<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable) where T : class
        {
            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());

            return mockSet;
        }

        public IEnumerable<SimulationPredictedObserved> GetValueSummary(BaseDatacontext db, int predictedObservedId, string valueName)
        {
            return (from pov in db.PredictedObservedValues
                    join pod in db.PredictedObservedDetails on pov.PredictedObservedDetailsID equals pod.ID
                    join s in db.Simulations on pov.SimulationsID equals s.ID
                    where pov.PredictedObservedDetailsID == predictedObservedId && pov.ValueName == valueName
                    select new SimulationPredictedObserved()
                    {
                        TableName = pod.TableName,
                        SimulationName = s.Name,
                        ValueName = pov.ValueName,
                        PredictedValue = Math.Round((double)pov.PredictedValue, 3),
                        ObservedValue = Math.Round((double)pov.ObservedValue, 3),
                        Difference = (double?)Math.Round((double)pov.PredictedValue - (double)pov.ObservedValue, 3)
                    })
                    .Distinct();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Henry Lu for the comprehensive answer.  I have now managed to get this working.  The Distinct was not really needed.  It was something that I added while trying to get it working.  I now only get back the 40 records that I am expecting.  The concatenated key for the joining existed in both tables.   My SimulationPredictedObserved class contains a subset of data from multiple other tables.  It turns out that I needed to add another field into this class and into my concatenated key for the join.